# Excel Spreadsheet Cell Isn't Changing Size

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I have a spread which I generate in VBA (Access) and basically when I generate the spread sheet, I want to be able to change the column width of "A" but when I try to change it to say 21, it will just change to 25 which isn't the value I want. The only value which works is 0.

```
With objExcelData
    Set .RecordSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql, dbOpenSnapshot)
    .AddCriteria "Date Range", DateRangeLongText(Me.StartDate, Me.EndDate)
    .Title = "Contact Details"
End With

With objExcelReport
    Set .xlsheet = objExcelAssist.StartNewSheet(0)
    Set .DataBag = objExcelData
    .ShowTitle = True
    .ShowCriteria = True
    .ShowTotalRow = False
End With

objExcelReport.GenerateSheet

' Basic formatting - SHEET 2 -
With objExcelAssist.worksheet
    .columns(1).ColumnWidth = 21
    .Rows(1).RowHeight = 21
    .columns("D:H").columns.Group
End With
```

Here I have .columns(1).ColumnWidth = 21

It adjusts the height as I need it to be, however the width doesn't change.

[image]

However the width hasn't changed at all

[image]

So the height changes, however the width doesn't, any ideas why?

Comment: check the unit used :) set it to 100 and see how many px that is

Comment: The value of the spreadsheet doesn't change at all, no matter the size

Comment: `but when I try to change it to say 21, it will just change to 25 which isn't the value I want.` well, maybe re-word your original sentence

Comment: It changes to 25 all the time, it's like it has a fixed position for 25 but can't figure out why it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put a comment "SHEET 2", are you sure you've not formatted the second sheet somewhere else by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Range("A1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 21
```

Comment: Nope, same problem as before.

Comment: Try to put more width than 25.14

Comment: I do, for some reason  it just reverts back to 25, can't put my finger on what it could be, might just leave it as 25.14

Comment: That's so strange. Can you share this file? to do some test.

Comment: Can't share it sorry, it's something I'm working on at work and can't exactly send it because it would mean giving away customers persona details

Comment: Include only the first row.

Comment: Can't do that sorry, it also requires installing other software from this company

Comment: Sorry, I cant help u then. I dont know more solutions for it. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried labeling it through columns as well?

```
ActiveCell.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 21
```

Also, you can make a small sub and call it from your code to see if that changes anything. Do any other column resizings work? Is `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`? I've also seen weird behaviours when you try and do that when you have other Events happening - might be a good thing to check out.